A doubt in Stateless hash based signature scheme standardized by NIST
The following are the parameters mentioned in the NIST standardized digital signature scheme based on Stateless Hash (FIPS-205).

It was mentioned in the report that the parameter set was designed to create relatively small signatures (‘s’) or to have relatively fast signature generation (‘f’).
I am unable to capture the meaning of 's' and 'f' here. Can anyone kindly explain the logic behind the introduction of the same?
